# Get rows in between date time values

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table like below

```
Id    DateTimeIn                DateTimeOut
1     2016-12-03 09:05:22.123   2016-12-03 09:05:22.123
2     2016-12-03 10:00:00.415   2016-12-03 10:40:00.415
3     2016-12-03 11:04:52.253   2016-12-03 11:35:22.123
```

I would like to bring the values that comes in between the time ranges.

```
declare @DateTimeIn date = '2016-12-03 11:00:52.213'
declare @DateTimeOut date = '2016-12-03 11:45:52.213'
```

The row with `Id 3` that comes in the input range. So I write the below query to bring that row as an output.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TimesheetEntries
WHERE @DateTimeIn BETWEEN DateTimeIn AND DateTimeOut 
   OR @DateTimeOut BETWEEN DateTimeIn AND DateTimeOut
```

But it bring no result. I dont know what is wrong in my query. Please help me!

Comment: If you have a variable of type `DATE`, you cannot initialize it with a **time portion** ! If you need the time portion, use `DATETIME2(n)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your variable is of type `datetime` and The column you are selecting is of type `datetime`.

```
declare @DateTimeIn datetime = '2016-12-03 11:00:52.213'
declare @DateTimeOut datetime = '2016-12-03 11:45:52.213'

SELECT * FROM TimesheetEntries
WHERE @DateTimeIn BETWEEN DateTimeIn and DateTimeOut 
OR @DateTimeOut BETWEEN DateTimeIn and DateTimeOut
```

Comment: Yeah. I came to know I was mad while query. :'(

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie So you figured it out?

Comment: Better yet: use `DATETIME2(n)` instead of `DATETIME` (it has better precision and a lot less hassles / issues....)

Comment: Will mark it an answer in 6 minutes as per the SO policy

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DateTimeIn datetime = '2016-12-03 11:00:52.213'
DECLARE @DateTimeOut datetime = '2016-12-03 11:45:52.213'

SELECT * FROM TimesheetEntries
WHERE 
(  
  DATEDIFF(DAY,DateTimeIn,@DateTimeIn) <= 0 AND
  DATEDIFF(DAY,DateTimeIn,@DateTimeOut) >= 0
) OR
(  
  DATEDIFF(DAY,DateTimeOut,@DateTimeIn) <= 0 AND
  DATEDIFF(DAY,DateTimeOut,@DateTimeOut) >= 0
)
```